# Shoes "Natural Sole" meaning

Tags: meaning

When buying a decent pair of shoes, I often see the statement "***with Natural Sole***" ("*Loafers in Tan Leather with natural sole.*") written in the description of the shoe. Does this mean that the shoe's sole is made out of natural materials e.g. **various types of wood** or does it refer to something else in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Natural Sole** means *a sole made of natural materials*. **Leather** is a natural material, so **"Loafers in Tan Leather with natural sole."** are a natural footwear. By adding **"natural"** the manufacturers mostly imply **"allowing the wearer's foot to breathe."**

*Natural Sole* are footwear made of (from) wood, papyrus, palm leaves, (cowhide) leather, ostrich skin, anaconda skin, elephant skin, and even cotton.

Comment: As a challenge, can you define "natural"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo There's no need in that... Any dictionary states that **"natural"** means *existing in or derived from nature; not made or caused by humankind*

Comment: What is the difference between "derived" and "made"?  Is rubber derived from nature?  [The challenge is to present a definition that needs no refinement or clarification :)  ]

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo And are you mentioning **natural rubber** or **synthetic rubber**? The first is derived from nature while the second one is made by humankind.